# How can I use my spritesheet of icons in react native?

Tags: react-native, sprite-sheet

How can I properly use sprite sheets in react-native? Or do people typically load icons separately and not use sprite sheets? Mind you this is not sprites for animation, just pure icons.

For example here is my sheet...

[image]

And here is the css for one icon...

```css
.Sprite {
  background-image: url(./assets/images/spritesheet.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
}
.IconMenu30px {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-position: -53px -5px;
}
```

And I tried to translate this into React Native like this...

```js
<Image source={require("../assets/images/spritesheet.png")} style={styles.menuIcon} />

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 menuIcon: {
    width: 30,
    height: 30,
  },
})
```

But apparently there is no **background position** attribute in React Native.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
<ImageBackground />
```

This might help with your issue

Comment: Yes I did but it didn't work out, so I just ended up breaking my icons in the sprite sheets into individual files and loading each one in a global js file holding all my images. Was hoping for a better way, but this works, though tedious!